I am trying to implement an AVL Tree in a python script. the tree can be traversed in ( Pre-order, In-order and Post-order)
The program should start by initializing an empty AVL tree. The program takes one line as input. The
input line contains n “modification moves” separated by spaces (1 ≤ n ≤ 100). The available modification
moves are:

Aint (Character A followed by an int value between 1 and 100): A3 means insert value 3 into the AVL
tree. If 3 is already in the tree, do nothing.
Dint (Character D followed by an int value between 1 and 100): D3 means delete value 3 from the AVL
tree. If 3 is not in the tree, do nothing.

Your input is then followed by exactly one Traversal Mode (PRE or POST or IN): If the Mode is PRE,
then you should print out the tree (in its current situation) in pre-order. If the tree is empty, print out
EMPTY. Otherwise, print out the values separated by spaces. POST and IN are handled similarly.
The Following is my main.py:
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key
        self.height = 1

class AVL_Tree:
    def insert(self, root, key):
        # Step 1: Perform normal BST insertion
        if not root:
            return Node(key)
        elif key < root.val:
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, key)
        elif key > root.val:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, key)
        else:
            # Duplicate keys are not allowed in the AVL tree
            return root

        # Step 2: Update the height of the ancestor node
        root.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(root.left), self.getHeight(root.right))

        # Step 3: Get the balance factor
        balance = self.getBalance(root)

        # Step 4: If the node becomes unbalanced, then try out the 4 cases
        # Left Left Case
        if balance > 1 and key < root.left.val:
            return self.rightRotate(root)

        # Right Right Case
        if balance < -1 and key > root.right.val:
            return self.leftRotate(root)

        # Left Right Case
        if balance > 1 and key > root.left.val:
            root.left = self.leftRotate(root.left)
            return self.rightRotate(root)

        # Right Left Case
        if balance < -1 and key < root.right.val:
            root.right = self.rightRotate(root.right)
            return self.leftRotate(root)

        return root

    def delete(self, root, key):
        if not root:
            return root

        if key < root.val:
            root.left = self.delete(root.left, key)
        elif key > root.val:
            root.right = self.delete(root.right, key)
        else:
            # Nodes with only one child or no child
            if root.left is None:
                return root.right
            elif root.right is None:
                return root.left

            # Node with two children: Get the inorder successor (smallest in the right subtree)
            temp = self.getMinValueNode(root.right)
            root.val = temp.val
            root.right = self.delete(root.right, temp.val)

        # If the tree had only one node then return
        if root is None:
            return root

        # Update the height of the current node
        root.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(root.left), self.getHeight(root.right))

        # Get the balance factor
        balance = self.getBalance(root)

        # If the node becomes unbalanced, then try out the 4 cases
        # Left Left Case
        if balance > 1 and self.getBalance(root.left) >= 0:
            return self.rightRotate(root)

        # Left Right Case
        if balance > 1 and self.getBalance(root.left) < 0:
            root.left = self.leftRotate(root.left)
            return self.rightRotate(root)

        # Right Right Case
        if balance < -1 and self.getBalance(root.right) <= 0:
            return self.leftRotate(root)

        # Right Left Case
        if balance < -1 and self.getBalance(root.right) > 0:
            root.right = self.rightRotate(root.right)
            return self.leftRotate(root)

        return root

    def leftRotate(self, z):
        y = z.right
        T2 = y.left
        y.left = z
        z.right = T2
        z.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(z.left), self.getHeight(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(y.left), self.getHeight(y.right))
        return y

    def rightRotate(self, z):
        y = z.left
        T3 = y.right
        y.right = z
        z.left = T3
        z.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(z.left), self.getHeight(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(y.left), self.getHeight(y.right))
        return y

    def getHeight(self, root):
        if not root:
            return 0
        return root.height

    def getBalance(self, root):
        if not root:
            return 0
        return self.getHeight(root.left) - self.getHeight(root.right)

    def getMinValueNode(self, root):
        current = root
        while current.left is not None:
            current = current.left
        return current

    def preOrder(self, root):
        res = []
        if root:
            res.append(root.val)
            res.extend(self.preOrder(root.left))
            res.extend(self.preOrder(root.right))
        return res

    def inOrder(self, root):
        res = []
        if root:
            res.extend(self.inOrder(root.left))
            res.append(root.val)
            res.extend(self.inOrder(root.right))
        return res

    def postOrder(self, root):
        res = []
        if root:
            res.extend(self.postOrder(root.left))
            res.extend(self.postOrder(root.right))
            res.append(root.val)
        return res

def process_commands(input_line):
    commands = input_line.split()
    tree = AVL_Tree()
    root = None
    for command in commands[:-1]:  # Last command is the type of traversal
        if command.startswith('A'):
            value = int(command[1:])
            root = tree.insert(root, value)
        elif command.startswith('D'):
            value = int(command[1:])
            root = tree.delete(root, value)

    # Determine the type of traversal
    traversal_command = commands[-1]
    if traversal_command == "PRE":
        result = tree.preOrder(root)
    elif traversal_command == "IN":
        result = tree.inOrder(root)
    elif traversal_command == "POST":
        result = tree.postOrder(root)

    if not result:
        return "EMPTY"
    return " ".join(map(str, result))

# To run the program, you would typically wrap this in a block that takes input, e.g.:
input_line = input()
output = process_commands(input_line)
print(output)


Right now as an example if I enter the following as an input:
A1 A2 A3 A5 D3 D5 IN
The output should be:
1 2
It appears to work for any case which has the traversal mode IN, but it only works partially when the traversal mode is PRE or POST. This is where I am getting stuck because I have combed through the code but I cannot understand where the issue seems to be. I just really wanted a fresh set of eyes to look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong. I have asked chatGPT but it seems to hallucinate when I ask anything remotely complicated.

"I have combed through the code": but have you run your code with a debugger?
